# Controller & Model issue in CakePHP 2.3.5

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

i'm having an issue with this (the database design is in spanish):

I have a controller ProfesionalController.php and a model Called ProfesionalModel.php, in the ProfesionalModel im using

```
public $useTable = 'profesional';
```

and in the controller I'm using

```
public $uses = array('Profesional');
```

but for some reason the Model is not being read from the Controller, I wrote a test function in the Model, something like this:

```
public function detalleProfesional(){
    return (1);
  }
```

And when I call this function in the controller with $this->Profesional->detalleProfesional() nothing happens.
I also have a $hasMany declared in the Model and when I made a debug($this->Profesional) this shows an AppModel but the $hasMany is not showed

any ideas?
thanks a lot for your time and best regards!

NOTE: I forgot, the name of the table in the db is 'profesional' and I'm using

```
Inflector::rules('plural', array('irregular' => array('profesional' => 'profesional')));
```

in the bootstrap.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model file name should be **Profesional.php**

Also, by cake conventions (I know it's spanish, but still), it should be **ProfesionalesController.php** (plural). If you keep it as **ProfesionalController.php** it won't give problems though.

Comment: The solution was name the Model "Profesional.php"! thanks for your answer!